# SQLAlchemy 2.0 - count simple stuff

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm very irritated, that it takes me so long to do stuff. I try to get a response in ORM mode:

1. one row
2. 3 columns: count_total, count_true, share

My code so far which I am using to create 2 rows an calculating in python:

```py
    async with self.session_context() as session:
        query = (
            select(
                distinct(db_model.Review.replied).label("replied"),
                func.count("*").label("count"),
            )
            .where(db_model.Review.location_id == location_id)
            .group_by("replied")
        )
        result = await session.execute(query)
```

which gives me what I've written there:

```
replied;count
True;123
False;234
```

But I can't find the solution have it like:

```
total;replied;share
357;123;0.344
```

I tried subqueries, inline counting, a `case when` variant and I always break something :/.

Answer (score 2):

When you get rid of the group by, you get only one row, tzhe rest is calculating

```
async with self.session_context() as session:
    query = (
        select(
            
            func.count("*").label("total"),
            func.count("*").filter(ddb_model.Review.replied==True).label("replied"),
            (func.count("*").filter(ddb_model.Review.replied==True) / func.count("*")).label("share") ,
        )
        .where(db_model.Review.location_id == location_id)

    )
    result = await session.execute(query)
```